# Visual studio 2017 offline

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My work space is visual basic, visual c++ , Sql in my current vs2013 which I provuded in picture, There is a lot of confusion in downloading vs2017 offline, so I need help in command to download offline for specific visual basic, visual c++, sql server

Comment: Too many things I don't understand. Please clarify your question. Are you looking for a download link or what?

Comment: As Microsoft experts tells its possible to download offline files of vs2017 by command pronpt, but it will downloads all the components to disk by doing commond vs_community__2145757475.1491282764.exe --layout c:\vs2017Test1\vs2017offline --lang en-US

Comment: You should run the installation file and choose which packages to install and which not

Comment: But those are online file, so we can't save these for later!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can download setup full packages in this site: https://www.nosware.com/visual-studio-2017-offline-installer/1528/

There is two option in there: first ±2GB for Desktop Development Only like: VB.NET, Csharp and C++, if you want full packages ±23GB, you can scroll down in bottom to download in two part, just using winrar to extract part file. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the following link and download the ISO version of VS2017, that will allow you to install VS while not connected to the internet.

https://developerinsider.co/download-visual-studio-2017-web-installer-iso-community-professional-enterprise/

Comment: Thats right but it downloads unnecessary things . That means all the content. But I only need to download vb, c++，sql

Comment: @Rakshith I don't think you can download only those packages in an offline manner.

Comment: Few more things to share. There somebody told me abouut this method Type the command: vs_community__2145757475.1491282764.exe --layout c:\vs2017Test1\vs2017offline --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data --lang en-US  it is about 817 MB offline files but it commits with error while installing